# No module named Python

Tags: python, bat, файловая-система, модули

Файловая структура:

```
|-- data/
|   |-- etc..
|
|-- project/
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- main.py
|
|-- scripts/
|   |-- tele_lib.py
|   |-- imap_lib.py
|
|-- README.md
|-- start.bat
```

Импорт из main.py:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '../')
from scripts.tele_lib import Telegram
from scripts.imap_lib import CheckMailbox
```

Сам start.bat:

```
start cmd /k "python mail_to_telegram/main.py"
```

При запуске start.bat выводится ошибка:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scripts.tele_lib'
```

Как в main.py правильно импортировать модуль?

Comment: Почему Вы решили запускать файл через `start.bat`? Я бы советовал оформить всё [пакетом](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages) и вынести `main.py` в его корень. Тогда не было бы никаких проблем с импортом и не пришлось бы вставлять ничего в PATH

Comment: Из-за [этого](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193161/what-is-the-best-project-structure-for-a-python-application) вопроса.

Comment: Я глянул мельком ответы на тот вопрос. Мнений очень много. Но заметьте, в ответах приведены деревья, отражающие структуру проекта. И в корневой директории каждого дерева есть файл `setup.py`, который и запускается. Остальной код находится относительно этого файла. А вы пытаетесь из `main.py` обратиться к родительскому каталогу

Comment: Попробуйте переписать программу, используя относительный импорт внутри пакета

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы исполняете файл `start.bat`. Поэтому и относительный путь, который Вы вставляете через `sys.path.insert(0, '../')`, будет указывать на директорию **относительно `start.bat`**.

Используйте полный путь. Например:

```py
sys.path.insert(0, 'C:/Users/Username/Desktop/mail_to_telegram/')
```

Answer (score 0):

В папку scripts добавить файл `__init__.py`

Comment: Ошибку пишет всё ещё.

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scripts.tele_lib'

Answer (score 0):

Надо было изменить start.bat на это:

```
start cmd /k " cd mail_to_telegram && python main.py"
```

Comment: Это не решает проблему относительного импорта. Если Вы попытаетесь запустить `start.bat` из другой директории, то путь снова нужно будет менять

Comment: Но start.bat всегда будет в этой директории. Скрипт сам python main.py запускается, а через start.bat не запускался.

Comment: Я понимаю, что скрипт всегда будет в этой директории. Но запускать то его можно из разных. Предположим, что `start.bat` находится в директории `project`. В консоли перейдите на директорию выше и попробуйте запустить: `project\start.bat`

Comment: Тогда да, не запускается. Просто писать весь путь через str не очень. Если переносить на другую машину, то надо будет писать путь заново.